# see the view(A.view) after A(UIViewController) presentViewController:B(UIViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios

My problem is this: [A presentViewController:B] but i want see the A's view.
 I am such a solution to the problem.

In other words，i want  a distinct picture from UIWindow.

```
UIWindow  *_applicationWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_applicationWindow.bounds.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[_applicationWindow.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *imageTemp = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView *_imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] init] autorelease];
_imageView.image = imageTemp;
[B.veiw addSubview:_imageView];
```

but the _imageView indistinct。

Thanks.

Comment: please be more descriptive in what you are doing...

Comment: i want get a distinct picture from UIWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not 100% sure that I understand your question, but I'll give it a try

When presenting a view controller on an iPhone it will cover the full screen. On an iPad you can set the UIModalPresentationPageSheet or UIModalPresentationFormSheet.

To show more than 1 view controller at a time on an iPhone (or in another presentation mode than what UIModalPresentationPageSheet or UIModalPresentationFormSheet can offer) you will have to use something introduced in iOS 5 called view controller containment.

The methods you will have to look at are:

```
addChildViewController:
removeFromParentViewController
willMoveToParentViewController:
didMoveToParentViewController:
```

in UIViewController.

Comment: How did it go? Successful?

Comment: addChildViewController:  Thanks.

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as a solution to your problem